# How to draw 4 lines in onDraw? - android

Tags: android

Back with another question,

How do i draw 4 lines in onDraw?
these are 4 constant lines with red color that represents my border of the view.
i tried drawing and could only draw 1 line and even that wasnt in the same width as my screen.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint redPaint = new Paint();
    redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    redPaint.setStrokeWidth(5); // set stroke so you can actually see the lines

    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), 0, redPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth(), 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), redPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), 0, getMeasuredHeight(), redPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), 0, 0, redPaint);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void    drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint)
Draw a line segment with the specified start and stop x,y coordinates, using the specified paint.
```

#

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.Red);

onDraw( Canvas canvas){
     canvas.drawLine(x,y,x1,y1, paint);
     canvas.drawLine(x,y,x1,y1, paint);
     canvas.drawLine(x,y,x1,y1, paint);
     canvas.drawLine(x,y,x1,y1, paint);
}
```

change the value of (x,y) and (x1,y1)